# Immutable values in F#

Tags: f#

I'm just getting started in F# and have a basic question.

Here's the code:

```
let rec forLoop body times =
    if times <= 0 then
        ()
    else
        body()
        forLoop body (times - 1)
```

I don't get the concept of how when you define a variable it is a value and immutable.  Here, the value is changing in order to loop.  How is that different from a variable in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform a call (any call), the runtime allocates a new stack frame and stores parameters and local variables of the called function in the new stack frame. When you perform a recursive call, the allocated frames contain variables with the same names, but these are stored in different stack frames.

To demonstrate this, I'll use a slightly simplified version of your example:

```
let rec forLoop n = 
  if times > 0 then 
    printf "current %d" n
    forLoop body (n - 1)
```

Now, let's say that we call `forLoop 2` from some top-level function or module of a program. The runtime allocates the stack for the call and stores the value of the parameter in the frame representing the `forLoop` call:

```
+----------------------+
| forLoop with n = 2   |
+----------------------+
| program              |
+----------------------+
```

The `forLoop` function prints `2` and continues running. It performs a recursive call to `forLoop 1`, which allocates a new stack frame:

```
+----------------------+
| forLoop with n = 1   |
+----------------------+
| forLoop with n = 2   |
+----------------------+
| program              |
+----------------------+
```

Since `1 > 0` the program enters the `then` branch once again, prints `1` and makes one more recursive call to the `forLoop` function:

```
+----------------------+
| forLoop with n = 0   |
+----------------------+
| forLoop with n = 1   |
+----------------------+
| forLoop with n = 2   |
+----------------------+
| program              |
+----------------------+
```

At this point, the `forLoop` function returns without making any other calls and stack frames are removed one by one as the programs returns from all the recursive calls. As you can see from the diagrams, we created three different variables that were stored on different stack frames (but all of them were named `n`).

It is also worth noting that the F# compiler performs various optimizations such as *tail-call*, which can replace a call and an allocation of a new stack frame with a use of mutable variable (which is more efficient). However, this is just an optimization and you don't need to worry about that if you want to understand the mental model of recursion.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, each recursion corresponds to a different stack frame within which the value of temp is immutable?

Answer (score 5):

it is not changing. you use recursion. **that** variable remains unchanged, but it is subtracted one and passed to function. function is same in this case.

stack will look like

```
forLoop body 0
 |
 forLoop body 1
   |
   forLoop body 2
```

Answer (score 5):

The code presented would not be represented as a for loop in C#, it would be recursive (something like this):

```
void ForLoop(int times, Action body)
{
  if (times <= 0)
  {
     return;
  }
  else
  {
     body();
     ForLoop(times - 1, body);
  }
}
```

As you can see, the value `times` is not changed at any point.

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of `times` in each recursive call is a different object in memory.  If `body()` uses `times` in any way, it captures the immutable value from the current stack frame, which is different from values in subsequent recursive calls.

Below are a C# and F# program that show one way the difference may be important.

C# program - prints some random number:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void ForLoop(int n)
    {
        while (n >= 0)
        {
            if (n == 100)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((_) => { Console.WriteLine(n); });
            }
            n--;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ForLoop(200);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

F# program - always prints 100:

```
open System
open System.Threading 
let rec forLoop times = 
    if times <= 0 then 
        () 
    else 
        if times = 100 then
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(fun _ -> 
                Console.WriteLine(times)) |> ignore
        forLoop (times - 1) 

forLoop 200
Thread.Sleep(2000)
```

The differences arise because the lambda passed to `QueueUserWorkItem` in the C# code captures a mutable variable, whereas in the F# version it captures an immutable value.

Comment: Hmmm... isn't the "in memory" story an implementation detail?  I think things are clearer when described in terms of bindings and values, which seem to be what defines the observable behavior.  Also, on an even more pedantic note, I wouldn't use the term "object" when referring to `times` since it's never boxed as far as I can see.

Comment: @kvb, yes, I am just trying to provide a potentially useful mental model (which may not be the actual way things are realized in the implementation).